# How to get right character in excel file when import?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, datetime

I have a file excel , i upload file , read it and show in gridview , it's ok , but format is wrong(data gender and data birthday not same) , this is excel data

[image]

And this is my code

```html
   public void BindGridView()
        {
            string FilePath = ResolveUrl("~/Uploads/"); // Give Upload File Path
            string filename = string.Empty;
            if (FileUploadToServer.HasFile) // Check FileControl has any file or not
            {
                try
                {
                    string[] allowdFile = { ".xls", ".xlsx" };
                    string FileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadToServer.PostedFile.FileName).ToLower();// get extensions
                    bool isValidFile = allowdFile.Contains(FileExt);

                    // check if file is valid or not
                    if (!isValidFile)
                    {
                        lblMsg.Visible = true;
                        lblMsg.Style.Add("color", "red");
                        lblMsg.Text = "Please upload only Excel";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int FileSize = FileUploadToServer.PostedFile.ContentLength; // get filesize
                        if (FileSize <= 1048576) //1048576 byte = 1MB
                        {
                            filename = Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath(FileUploadToServer.FileName));// get file name
                            FileUploadToServer.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(FilePath) + filename); // save file to uploads folder
                            string filePath = Server.MapPath(FilePath) + filename;
                            string conStr = "";
                            if (FileExt == ".xls") // check for excel file type
                            {
                                conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                            }
                            else if (FileExt == ".xlsx")
                            {
                                conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                            }

                            conStr = String.Format(conStr, filePath, "Yes");
                            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
                            OleDbCommand ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand();
                            ExcelCommand.Connection = con;
                            con.Open();
                            DataTable ExcelDataSet = new DataTable();
                            ExcelDataSet = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            if (ExcelDataSet != null && ExcelDataSet.Rows.Count > 0)
                            {
                                string SheetName = ExcelDataSet.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString(); // get sheetname
                                ExcelCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
                                OleDbDataAdapter ExcelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ExcelCommand);
                                ExcelAdapter.SelectCommand = ExcelCommand;
                                ExcelAdapter.Fill(dt);
                            }
                            con.Close();
                            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0) // Check if File is Blank or not
                            {
                                grvBatchUpload.DataSource = dt;
                                grvBatchUpload.DataBind();
                                lblMsg.Visible = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblMsg.Visible = true;
                                lblMsg.Style.Add("color", "red");
                                lblMsg.Text = "There are No Rows in this File!!!";
                            }
                            //FilePath = ResolveUrl("~/Uploads/");
                            //string fileName = Server.MapPath(FilePath) + filename;
                            //FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);
                            //if (f.Exists)
                            //{
                            //    f.IsReadOnly = false;
                            //    f.Delete();
                            //}
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lblMsg.Visible = true;
                            lblMsg.Style.Add("color", "red");
                            lblMsg.Text = "Attachment file size should not be greater then 1 MB!";
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblMsg.Visible = true;
                    lblMsg.Style.Add("color", "red");
                    lblMsg.Text = "Error occurred while uploading a file: " + ex.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblMsg.Visible = true;
                lblMsg.Style.Add("color", "red");
                lblMsg.Text = "Please select a file to upload.";
            }
        }
```

And the result 
[image]

Can you see it.Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with Gender? While I don't think a checkbox is an accurate way to describe gender, the excel sheet says true / false, which is correlating to the Checked state of the checked box. The results seem correct. As far as the date however, not sure why Candy doesn't have one but the other two do. Does the cell in Excel have formatting set to be a date or something else?

Comment: Hi sab669, in file excel , format all is general, but seem birthday show in gridview is wrong. I want to same `23/12/1990 ; 1/1/1900 ; 1/12/1900` , the result `1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM 1/12/1900 12:00:00 AM` wrong